# why is my jquery Append not working properly?

Tags: jquery, append

I have this problem I'm working on which is giving me a headache, because I can't seem to find where the bug is. Here's the markup:

```
<div class="excerpt">
     <p>...</p>
</div>

<div class="bio">
     <p>...</p>
</div>
```

When the user clicks a button, I want to display whatever is in div.bio to show in div.excerpt. Here is my click() function.

```
$('.button').click( function() { 
     var bio = $('.bio p'); 
     var excerpt = $('.excerpt'); 

     // empty 
     excerpt.empty(); 

     // replace
     bio.appendTo(excerpt); 

});
```

The problem is that this code **removes the paragraphs** from the bio during the append. Is there a way to simply append and not remove the elements from the source? Or am I doing something else wrong?

Comment: Duplicate of [How to append one jQuery element already in the DOM to another element?](/q/6364633/4642212).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use [`append`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) or [`appendTo`](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/) on existing parts of the DOM tree you are actually *moving* them. As the documentation states,

> If an element selected this way is inserted elsewhere, it will be
>   moved into the target (not cloned):

You need to also use [`clone`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) to add a copy of the elements to the tree. For example:

```
bio.clone().appendTo(excerpt);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, as Jon suggested:

```
 $('.button').click( function() { 
      var bio = $('.bio p'); 
      var excerpt = $('.excerpt'); 

      // empty 
      excerpt.empty(); 

      // replace
      bio.clone().appendTo(excerpt); 
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

While some of the other answers will probably work, this seems pretty terse.

```
$('.button').click( function() { 
    $('.excerpt').html($('.bio').html());
});
```